# Comparing two strings containing '_' lexicographically in bash

Tags: bash

I need to compare strings in a bash script lexicographically. The problem is that it seems that bash totally ignores '_' characters, as if they were not there at all. In the ascii code table '_' is between the upper case letters and the lower case letters so I'd assume that A-Z < _ < a-z, and this is what actually happens on Mac OS, but not on Debian:

```
1   $ if [[ "ab" < "a_" ]]; then echo 1; fi
2   $ if [[ "ab" < "a_a" ]]; then echo 1; fi
3   $ if [[ "ab" < "a_c" ]]; then echo 1; fi
    1
4   $ if [[ "aZ" < "a_" ]]; then echo 1; fi
    $
```

Command #3 should be false as well, because '_' < 'b', while command #4 should be true because '_' > 'Z'.

The only logical explanation to me is that the '_' characters are simply omitted in Debian bash, so "ab" < "a" -> false, "ab" < "aa" -> false, "ab" < "ac" -> true, "aZ" < "a" -> false is what really is getting evaluated.

Is there any way in Debian bash to compare these strings treating their '_' characters as their ascii code would suggest?

Thanks

Comment: bash doesn't omit anything, it's related to the current locale

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the `[[ < ]]` operator depends on your current locale. This is also documented in [bash's manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> When used with [[, the ‘<’ and ‘>’ operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.

You can check your current locale using the command `locale`. When you run this command on your Mac OS and Debian you should get different results.

You can overwrite your system's locale for your script using `export LC_ALL=...`. The locale for sorting by ascii codes is `C`.

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8; [[ ab < a_c ]]; echo $?
0
$ export LC_ALL=C; [[ ab < a_c ]]; echo $?
1
```