# Value too great for base (error token is "2021_08_25")

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I have below files in a directory:

2021_08_26.txt

2021_09_2.txt

2021_08_25.txt

2021_08_27.txt

Out of these I want to delete the files which are older than 8 days based on the file names. Have written below script for this task.

```
#!/bin/bash

f8days=$(date +%F --date="-8 days")
for file in 20*
do
    if [[ $file -gt $f8days ]]
    then
        rm -rf "$file"
    fi
done
```

But while running my script I am facing the below mentioned errors:

```
./old-log-delete.sh: line 6: [[: 2021_08_25: value too great for base (error token is "2021_08_25")
./old-log-delete.sh: line 6: [[: 2021_08_26: value too great for base (error token is "2021_08_26")
./old-log-delete.sh: line 6: [[: 2021_08_27: value too great for base (error token is "2021_08_27")
./old-log-delete.sh: line 6: [[: 2021_09_2: value too great for base (error token is "2021_09_2")
```

What is the reason for this error and a possible solution?

Comment: `-gt` compares integers only, not strings. Use `>`.

Answer (score 1):

`-gt`, `-lt`, `-eq` operators are reserved for integer values.
`2021_08_25` is not an integer value. It contains `_` char who is not accepted.

Use `>`, `<`, `=` operators are used for string.

As you want, you can remove `_` like this sample:

```sh
strdate="2021_08_25"
intdate=${strdate//_/}
```

Answer (score 0):

I originally closed the question as a duplicate of [Comparing two strings containing '_' lexicographically in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62024681/comparing-two-strings-containing-lexicographically-in-bash), but since you are specifically trying to test if a file is older than a given date, I thought I might recommend the following instead:

```
touch -t $(date +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S --date="-8 days") boundary
for file in 20*; do
    if [[ $file -ot boundary ]]; then
        rm -rf -- "$file"
    fi
done
```

This creates an empty file with a modification date 8 days in the past, then checks if `$file` is older than that empty file.

---

While `bash` lets you compare strings lexicographically with `>`, the comparison is locale-dependent, whereas `-ot` is not.